# Attribute Error: at /auth/login/facebook/ Exception Value: operators

Tags: python, django, facebook

Am Using the following configuration with django

**cassandra-driver (3.1.0)**

**Django (1.9.4)**

**django-cassandra-engine (0.7.0)**

**django-oauth-toolkit (0.10.0)**

**django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 (1.0.4)**

**djangorestframework (3.3.2)**

**oauthlib (1.0.3)**

**python-social-auth (0.2.14)**

**Python 2.7.9** 

**My site settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django_cassandra_engine',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'oauth2_provider',
'userlogin',
'social.apps.django_app.default',
'rest_framework_social_oauth2'
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
        'NAME': 'sample',
        'TEST_NAME' : 'test_sample',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
        'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
        'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
        'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**Home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block main %}
<div>
  <h1>Third-party authentication demo</h1>

  <p>
    <ul>
      {% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
      <li>
        <a>Hello {{ user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}!</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'auth:logout' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Logout</a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with Facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with Google</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with Twitter</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Views.py**

 
    from django.shortcuts import render

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def home(request):
        context = RequestContext(request,
                                {'request': request,
                                'user': request.user})
        return render_to_response('home.html',
                                context_instance=context)
```

**URLS.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'userlogin.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls')),
url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
)
```

When I access the facebook authetication, i received the following error.

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  235.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  50.                         request.session.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in save
  80.             return self.create()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in create
  49.             self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_new_session_key
  155.             if not self.exists(session_key):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in exists
  45.         return self.model.objects.filter(session_key=session_key).exists()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in exists
  651.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in has_results
  501.         return compiler.has_results()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in has_results
  819.         return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  837.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  389.             where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  366.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  79.                 sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  366.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in as_sql
  160.         rhs_sql = self.get_rhs_op(connection, rhs_sql)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_rhs_op
  164.         return connection.operators[self.lookup_name] % rhs

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/base/__init__.py" in __getattr__
  103.         raise AttributeError(attr)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /auth/login/facebook/
Exception Value: operators
```

Can somebody please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are all your 3rd party packages compatible with Django 1.9.4?

Comment: thast an error of casandra not for the social login.

Comment: Well, I used pip to install them, so compatibility should be taken care of

Comment: Can anybody throw a light on this issue please? am still unable to figure out myself

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `django_cassandra_engine` as secondary database backend:

```
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'cassandra': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_db',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'replication': {
                'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                'replication_factor': 1
            },
            'connection': {
                'consistency': ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE,
                'retry_connect': True
            },
            'session': {
                'default_timeout': 10,
                'default_fetch_size': 10000
                # + All options for cassandra.cluster.Session()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have plans for using f.ex. `django.contrib.auth` or `django.contrib.admin`, then `django_cassandra_engine` has to be your **secondary** database backend (not *default* one).

Further instructions: https://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/guide/advanced_usage/#cassandra-as-secondary-database